# What could the link to the endpoint be?

Tags: java, rest, wildfly

I am following this tutorial http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/resteasy/wildfly-hello-world/

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloService {
    @GET
    @Path("/text")
    public String getHello () 
    {
        return "hello world!";
    } 


@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {
   
}
```

I managed to deploy my app, i see it in the wildfly admin console.
From there, i can see the context root, and when i try to access it, I get the "Forbidden" message. That is ok I think.

Problem is that I expect to get the "hello world!" when I access something like `http://localhost:8080/contextRootLocationThatIsForbidden/rest/hello/text`    ..instead I get "Not Found"

```
    <dependencies>

    <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in WildFly / JBoss EAP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Bean Validation Implementation 
       Provides portable constraints such as @Email 
       Hibernate Validator is shipped in WildFly / JBoss EAP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in WildFly / JBoss EAP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in WildFly / JBoss EAP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.3_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included in WildFly / JBoss EAP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in WildFly / JBoss EAP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- NEEDED because of XmlRootElement-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Is it not just `http://localhost:8080/rest/hello/text` ?

Comment: @QBrute 404 - Not Found for that one

Comment: If your POM looks exactly like the example, it should be http://localhost:8080/helloworld/rest/hello/text

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins the only difference is the project name, so instead of the /helloworld i have something else. I also notice something...when I navigate in the wildfly admin console, at the JAX-RS page, there are no entries. So it looks like widlfly doesn't even see my paths

Comment: Without seeing the full POM it's hard to tell what the issue could be.